# Renaming TABLE 101 to table101 in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So I have this table which got created from importing a csv. The name of the table is `TABLE 101`. Obviously queries won't work on it since it contains a space?

How do I rename it to `table101` or something else?

I've tried this:-

```
ALTER TABLE ['TABLE 101']
RENAME TO ['tavle101']
```

But it doesn't work, here's the error :-

Static analysis:

```
6 errors were found during analysis.
```

> Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 12)
>       Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 24)
>       Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 37)
>       Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 48)
>       A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "RENAME" at position 27)
>       Unrecognized alter operation. (near "RENAME" at position 27)
>       SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE ['TABLE 101'] RENAME TO ['tavle101']

MySQL said: Documentation
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '['TABLE 101']
>       RENAME TO ['tavle101']' at line 1

What am I doing wrong?

**Using MySQL with phpmyadmin**

Comment: Why do you use `[]`?

Comment: Use back ticks, `\`TABLE 101\``

Comment: @u_mulder I guess because the documentation uses [] for optional params

Comment: there are some examples in [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-examples.html). You just need to add backticks around TABLE 101, because of the space in the name

Comment: And if you use `phpmyadmin` there's a special button in Operations where you can rename table without all these.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `TABLE 101` RENAME TO `tavle101`;

Comment: Are you using the phpMyAdmin "rename" feature or entering the SQL manually? phpMyAdmin shouldn't generate that syntax since that's not valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Grave accent(``) character instead square bracket [].

```
    Rename TABLE `TABLE 101`  TO  tavle101;
```